# String models of particle physics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, string-theory, physical-constants

1. What general features of particle physics are derived/replicated by constructing string models of particle models?
2. How do such models address the fixing of free parameters like the masses and the coupling constants in the Standard Model?

I have a little bit of background knowledge of string theory, having studied the first part of Zweibach's book, but except from attending some talks on AdS/CFT correspondence and the string landscape I don't know much about it.

Comment: I think they can replicate two facts and a corollary right now: 1) There may be a universe, but there could also be a near infinite number of them. 2) There is gravity or at least something that could look like gravity if one squints real hard with two eyes.  3) It is impossible that string theory could possible be wrong, way too many way too smart people have spent way too much time on it. ;-)

Comment: @CuriousOne i understand your second pt. is valid that Einstein's field equations arise as a necessity while quantizing strings subject to Lorentz invariance, which is a very nice feature. but the first point is not exactly suitable for my answer, for we do not know which minima of the string landscape our universe is stuck in and thus can't make predictions..therefore i am asking what general features are exactly described by the theory that we know are there in today's particle physics..

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I am pretty sure that some aspects of string theory are possibly implemented in nature... if we spaghettify spacetime, quantum theory may, for a very short moment, look like string theory while we are disappearing in the rabbit hole, but that's like the appearance of anyons in solid state physics: interesting but not in any way shape or form fundamental. For my taste string theory hasn't been able to produce anything that looks like a convincing version of the next level of theory. Why would it have? There is no empirical data to fit the next theory to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While a very important question, I don't think my answer can do much justice in attempting to explain a gargantuan open problem in theoretical physics. But I can give you some overview and point you in the right direction.

As of now, everything is work in progress. There are a lot of issues with the standard model which current experimental data cannot validate such as why three families of fermions, why are there so many free parameters etc. What string theory needs to do is that it must provide a consistent formalism in which a 10 dimensional supersymmetric theory can yield a gauge theory (which can in principle reproduce the MSSM) coupled perturbatively to Einstein-Hilbert gravity in 4 dimensions. We know that string theory reproduces EH gravity.

For particle physics constructions, there are three highly followed methods as of today:

a) Calabi -Yau and orientifold compactification

b) Model building from D-branes

c) F-theory

I would suggest the book by [Uranga and Ibanez on String Theory and Particle Physics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521517524) which is very good and caters to the interests of a grad student to an experienced researcher.

One of the key ideas in string theory is to obtain the correct compactification from a 10 dimensional supersymmetric theory to a 4 dimensional non-supersymmetric theory. A very interesting avenue for this is the study of Calabi-yau manifolds for which a read of the excellent review by [Brian Green](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9702155) is recommended.

Finally, there is F theory. I wont go into the details of F theory here but there is a very nice review by [Timo Weigand](http://inspirehep.net/record/868993) on F theory and model building.

All these methods show a lot of promise and there is a lot of work being done in these areas but the questions that you are asking are still work in progress. The hope is that one can derive a model from string theory in 10 d a model of some gauge theory coupled perturbatively to gravity such that the gauge theory can explain the obtainment of the parameters in the standard model.

I would also recommend the lectures by [Frederik Denef](http://inspirehep.net/record/780946) and [Elias Kiritsis](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0310001) and references therein.

All in all string theory is still yet to recover the standard model but it is work in progress.

For a set of elementary introductions, I would recommend these notes by [Jan Louis](https://www.desy.de/~jlouis/Vorlesungen/SP_14/SP_14.pdf), and some notes by Fernando Quevedo which can be found [here](http://users.ictp.it/~pub_off/lectures/lns013/Quevedo/Quevedo.pdf) and [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9603074v2.pdf). These two people are two of the most influential string phenomenologists.

Answer (score 1):

"What general features of particle physics are derived/replicated by constructing string models of particle models?"

All of them. Essentially every field-theoretic property or phenomenon of the standard model, has a string-theoretic realization.

"How do such models address the fixing of free parameters like the masses and the coupling constants in the Standard Model?"

In principle, such quantities are determined by the choice of vacuum. For example, if a gauge field is realized by a brane stack, the coupling may equal the volume of the branes. But in practice, the ability to compute them is still limited.

Comment: I think the OP is rather asking about explicit stringy constructions that yield certain features of e.g. the standard model.